# is there a fork of jRails that works with Rails 2.3 and jQuery 1.4?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, jrails

We're rewriting a site using Rails, and the old site makes extensive use of jQuery v1.4 in its templates.  We'd like the old scripts to keep working, but we'd also like to use rails' javascript helpers for our own new scripts.  jRails sounds like what we want, but it only seems to support jQuery 1.3.  Is there a more up-to-date fork of jRails that works with Rails 2.3 and jQuery 1.4 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the last jrails version (jRails 0.4) was for jQuery 1.5

see the gihub page https://github.com/aaronchi/jrails
and a mirror of the original site, which is down by now
http://mirror.ozdiy.com/assets/b8/2f96a12bc919b37e09d303b86ea1b9_1251811910.html

so you should be fine to go.